# SQL Server on big machine falls over inexplicably

Tags: sql-server, performance, configuration

We've been doing some throughput testing with our web application.

The production application resides on a couple of machines in the amazon cloud, consisting of a web server and a database server.  We wanted to know if replacing the current database machine with a bigger one would increase throughput.

A workload was constructed, and run against machines configured identically to the production web and database servers (call them W and DB A).  Observing pegged cpu activity on DB A, we configured a database server(DB B)  with more cpu capacity and re ran the tests.

We were pleased with the results; response time was cut in half, cpu usage was down to 80 % or so.

Amazon has available one machine bigger (DB C), so we thought we'd do it again. (the cloud is great!)  But this time, the the workload started failing immediately, with deadlocks and time outs waiting for connections.  CPU utilization was pegged at 100 %.  The poor thing just couldn't keep up.

Having DB B still available, we pointed W back at DB B and verified the test; all was okay.  We pointed Web to DB C, and it fell over again.

One thing that was different between B and C, was that with B, the sysAdmin was able to image the disks from production.  However with C, the system drive couldn't be imaged, and so the machine was spun up with their latest version of SQL Server.

The data and log drives were available, so I configured the pre-installed SQL Server to attach the relevant .ldf and .mdf files (after having to use takeown and cacls to adjust the permissions of the files, which had their sids all messed up).  After attaching the db files to the database, I successfully logged in through the web application and clicked around to see that things appeared to be working.

The machines A B and C are rated at 26, 52 and 108 ECUs respectively (an ecu is a relative measure of integer performance). C is plenty big enough.  I'm wondering if there is some bonehead switch that I missed turning on while configuring machine 'C'?

Some stats on the machines tested:

- Name vCPU  ECU    Mem
- A.....8.....26.....30
- B....16.....55.....30
- C....32....108.....60

The error log indicated a 17054, but afterwards seemed to load and run SQL Server okay.

The error log also indicated that it detected 32 cpus when run on C, and made no complaint of licensing issues. I didn't think to check whether all cpus were being used during the execution of the test.

We've gone over the configuration options on both B and C; can't see any significant differences; SQL Manager wasn't running on C, but other than that, the instances were configured identically.

How could I go about determining why this is happening?

Comment: Just tried again.  I could see that all cpus were being excersized.  I checked max threads, and it was set to default for a 64 bit, 32 cpu machine ... 960.   The Sql Error log was fine, then suddenly... 'using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5', then 'Dump thread - spid = 0 , ec = 0x000000....'   then it did a stack dump, and sql server wedged until i restarted it.